# Is it possible to align two DIVs side by side if one is fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am trying setup a design where I would like a left bar for navigation and things that remains fixed and doesn't scroll, but have a content box next to it that does scroll as needed. The problem I'm running into, if I `position: fixed;` the first DIV it technically does what I want, but it overlaps the second DIV. I'm just creating this and using JsFiddle to test easily, so I don't have an actual working code other than this fiddle. I'll admit, I've been awake for about 30 hours now, so if this is a really silly oversight from me, please forgive me. Thanks!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ypL8ypsf/)

Comment: remove floats from one and two and add `margin-left:150px;` to two. This is another way. Like http://jsfiddle.net/ypL8ypsf/4/

Comment: `position: fixed` is relative to window, not the parent element.

Comment: @protocaolzero , my solution , is the solution you need ;) ask me if you have any difficulties !

Comment: Wow, thank all of you for your help! I got a good nights rest and realized that my entire issue was caused because I was using a percentage on the width. I decided, for now, to use a set width for both columns and that completely negated my problem. I went through and tried out every single answer given and I'll select the one that best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to write this code and it is responsive too.

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#one {
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
}
#two {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 0%;
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    background: #333;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the best answer I saw to the question in the way that I worded it, which I'll admit was very poorly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you add `position:fixed` the element is taken out of the flow and its basically functions in respect to the window .

so the following CSS :

```
#one {
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
}
```

25% is 25% of the window not 25% of `<div id="wrap">`(and hence the overlap) , if you take off the `position:fixed`  you'll see no overlap .

with position fixed , you probably want to have some left offset on `<div id="two">`,  you cal experiment with :

```
margin-left: // DO YOUR MATH.

padding-left: // DO YOUR MATH.
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! That would have fixed the problem if I had worded it correctly. I could have either used your margin and padding solution or just made my columns a smaller percentage to make up for the overlap. Thank you though for explaining your solution in such great detail, you did actually help me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You already have `height: 400px;` on your over `div` so specify the height to `#one` too http://jsfiddle.net/ypL8ypsf/5/

```
#one { 
    position:fixed;
    width:16%;
    background: #666;
    height:384px;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! The reason I had the height set there was to emulate a browser window, the actual live version will not have that set height. Thank you though, that was technically a correct answer to my poorly phrased question, but Jugal Panchal's answer best fit my solution. Thank you again though!

Answer (score 1):

This changes in `css` will solve your problem

```
#wrap {
background: #999;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
overflow: scroll;
}
#one {    
position: fixed;
width: 25%;
background: #666;
height: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
#two {    
width: 70%;
background: #333;
height: 100%;
display:inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:29%;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This didn't actually solve the problem. It left the overlap. However, you did provide an alternative to using a float that I didn't know about! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

If you have position :fixed on an element. it can only controlled by the browser window, cannot control by parent div. so if you add width: 25% it fill up 25% of your browser window. not in parent div.

i have 2 solutions,

1. use javascript. dynamically add width in 'px' and add position:
   fixed after
2. use position: absolute. instead of fixed. ( actually your height is 100% so it doesn't matter your position fixed. )

**1nd solution: javascript approach [sample code]**:

```
//remove position:fixed from #one 
#one {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
}

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var calWidth = $("#one").width(); //get the width
    $("#one").css({width:calWidth+'px',position:'fixed'}); //apply to the div
</script>
```

**2nd solution: CSS approach [sample code]**

```
#wrap{
    position:relative;
}
#one{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Your answer impressed me the most! Merely your understanding of javascript alone was nice! I did try your solutions and they did both work, but the javascript seemed a little bit of overkill for my actual problem. Thank you though, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding your current `float` and `position` styles with:

`float: left;`  and
`position: relative;`

Comment: I needed column one to remain fixed though and not scroll, so that didn't actually fix my problem. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing that DIV, I've float them both to the left and give the second DIV overflow-y scroll property.

Hope this can help you:

```
#wrap {
    background: #999;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
#one {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;   

}
#two {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background: #333;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

If it is not usefull you always can try some framework with default sidebars.

Comment: This solution almost worked, but the issue came with my horrible explanation of my problem. The wrap box I had setup in the fiddle was just to emulate a browser window, it wasn't meant to remain that way. I know you didn't know that, and I apologize for my poor explanation. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Although you could add some margin to the second div to displace it to the right, I don't think you should use fixed for this.
You should do this:

```
<div class="div1">This is not moving</div>
<div class="div2"> Loren ipsum...</div>

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.div1{
  background: #DDD;
  width:40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div2{
  background: #EEE;
  width:60%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Here is a pen for you: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/bdBWJV

Comment: That solution didn't actually solve the problem, but I do see where you were going. I wasn't actually planning on leaving my two columns inside a wrapper like that, that wrapper was just meant to emulate a browser window. Thank you though, I do appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what you want but by adding more div.
the HTML would be

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="testone"><div id="one"></div></div>
<div id="test"><div id="two">Lorem ipsum...
</div></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and the css then

```
#wrap {
background: #999;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
overflow: scroll;
}
#testone{
float: left;
width: 25%;
background: #666;
height: 100%;
}
#one {
position: fixed;
}
#test{
float: right;
width: 75%;
height: 100%;
}
#two {
background: #333;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked! The problem (and I know I didn't explain this correctly) is that I needed the background of column one to remain fixed, as it was going to overlay an image and be transparent. Thank you though, I really do appreciate it!